# How to display the text of particular item in the modal window by passing the id value in the modal window?

Tags: php

I have a code of an html for different number of packages like given below :

```
 <article class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 baner-box">
                    <div class="thumb-pad1">
                                              <div class="thumbnail">
                                                  <figure>
                                                        <img src="images/packages/<?php echo $arr["package_image"]; ?>" alt="">
                                                        <h3>Hi</h3>
                                                        <h4>Welcome</h4>
                                                        <p>fggf</p>
                                                        <div class="package-btn">
                                                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-submit" >Book / Enquiry / Pay</a>

                                                        </div>
                                                  </figure>
                                              </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

When i am clicking the button Book / Enquiry / Pay in the above code, a modal window gets opened. The modal code is shown below :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enquiry / Booking / Payment</h4>

        </div>

     <div id="contact_form_bg">
     <div class="form_header">


      </div>
     <div class="contact_form body">
     <form action="#contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>

      <li>
      <p class="left">

        <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" required>
      </p>
      <p class="left">

        <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="Time" required>      
      </p>
      <p class="left">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>      
      </p>
      <p class="left">

       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact Number" required>  
      </p>
    </li>

    <li>
      <p class="left">
       <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Your Email" required>  

      </p>
       <p class="left">

        <input type="text" name="no-of-people" placeholder="Selected Package">        
      </p>
      <p class="left">


  <select>
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Your Package Type</option>
   <option value="1"> 14 Days - Rs.20000 </option>
   <option value="2">21 Days - Rs.25000</option>
    </select>            
      </p>
       <p class="left">


  <select>
     <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
    <option value="1">Female</option>
    <option value="2">Male</option>
 </select>           
      </p>


    </li>        

    <li>
     <p class="txtarea-style">
      <textarea cols="46" rows="3" name="comments" placeholder="Message With Us ...."></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
      <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Enquiry">
      </p>
      <p>
      <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" value="Booking">
      </p>
     <!-- <p>
       <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-submit" >Booking with Payment </a>
      </p>-->

    </li>


     </ul>
   </form>  
 </div>
 </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the value of corresponding package in the  tag in the selected package field in the modal window  by passing the id value of that particular package which is in the database and display all the values in the , and

tags. For each package there will be this article code and I want to display all the values in the  for each package in the corresponding modal window in the selected package input field by passing the id value of that particular package in the database.

Comment: Hey nobody here !!